# How to paste HTML to clipboard with GTK+

Tags: gtk, clipboard

How do I paste HTML to the clipboard so that it is recognized as HTML in applications such as Open Office and MS Word? It is possible when using gtkhtml or gecko if you've already rendered it, but I need a straight GTK+ solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call [`gtk_clipboard_set_with_data`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/gtk-Clipboards.html#gtk-clipboard-set-with-data) or [`gtk_clipboard_set_with_owner`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/gtk-Clipboards.html#gtk-clipboard-set-with-owner), passing a [`GtkTargetEntry`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/gtk-Selections.html#GtkTargetEntry) with `"text/html"` as the value for the `target` field.

It's good practice to also provide `"UTF8_STRING"` and `"STRING"` targets for applications that don't support HTML.

Here's an example of some code that does this: [GEdit HTML clipboard plugin](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#MlaRntO6oo4/files/htmlclipboard.tar.gz|vDouRpSARFY/htmlclipboard/gedit-htmlclipboard-plugin.c).

Comment: That last link to "GEdit HTML clipboard plugin" seems to be broken.

Comment: And ""text/plain;charset=utf-8"