# Dump X clipboard data with GTK+ or PyGTK

Tags: gtk, clipboard, pygtk, x11

How do I paste HTML data from the X clipboard using PyGTK/GTK+?

I would need something like [xclip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip), but with the ability to output clipboard data as HTML, not just as plain text. I'm using PyGTK, but I am not afraid of plain GTK+ in C.

I've read [GtkClipboard](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/gtk-Clipboards.html) and PyGTK's [gtk.Clipboard](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/2.16/class-gtkclipboard.html) references, and I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992869/how-to-paste-html-to-clipboard-with-gtk), but I would need a small example to get me started.

Comment: Similar: https://askubuntu.com/a/428734/2273 (maybe a dup?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated answer

The original answer (below) used an old API, here is an updated version:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
text = clipboard.wait_for_contents(Gdk.Atom.intern("text/html", True))
print(text.get_data())
```

Note also that your application may use a different target than "text/html": you can check which targets are available with:

```py
def get_targets(clipboard, targets, n_targets):
    assert len(targets) == n_targets
    print(f"There are {n_targets} targets:")
    print("\n".join(map(str, targets)))

clipboard.request_targets(get_targets)
```

### Original answer

Found it. I used something like this:

```
clipboard = gtk.Clipboard()
target = "text/html"
clipboard.wait_for_contents(target)
clipboard.request_contents(target, dump_clipboard_callback)
```

And then the callback function can simply extract the data:

```
def dump_clipboard_callback(clipboard, selection_data, data=None):
    print selection_data.data
```

Comment: I believe `wait_for_contents` here is redundant. You either use `request contents` with a callback, or `wait_for_contents` and use its return value. Note that both methods go back into the main loop, so you won't block if you use wait_for_contents.